# Determine the realtions ($\mathcal{O}$,$\Theta$,$\Omega$ ) between $f(n) = \ln(n^{c} + n^{d})$ and $g(n)=\ln(n^{a} + n^{b})$

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

I am trying to determine the realtions ($\mathcal{O} $,$\Theta$,$\Omega$ ) between :
 $$f(n) = \ln(n^{c} + n^{d})$$
$$g(n)=\ln(n^{a} + n^{b})$$ 
Note: $a,b,c,d>0$

I need some advice how to use the $\log$ rules to simplify it by using limits.
thanks.

Comment: You need to do this for all possible values of a,b,c,d>0?

Comment: yes, but maybe after simplify it the result will depened on the combinations of a+b or c+d, but its only my opinion.

Comment: $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ for all choices of exponents.

Answer (score 1):

As Antonio Vargas remarked, $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ for any choice $a,b,c,d>0$. More precisely,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln (n^c+n^d)}{\ln(n^a+n^b) } = \frac{\max(c,d)}{\max(a,b)}
$$
Indeed, the sum of two negative numbers is within the factor of two of their maximum. This factor, pulled out of logarithm, becomes a negligible additive constant.